# I need a minimal QT 5.0 Compiler install for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: qt

I need a minimal QT 5.0 Compiler install for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

I just need to run qmake and have the QT includes, macros and libraries work under g++. I do not need The QT GUI development environment.

I tried the following...
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.0.run
... Follow instructions... At the end I get "Warning: QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded" which I need.

So I had to build from source, which takes overnight! (but does work)...
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
git checkout 5.5
... Follow instructions... It does work.

I only want the compiler, not everything! How do I get that?

Alan.

Comment: "the compiler"? which "compiler"?

Comment: Did you consider upgrade your Ubuntu? It should be much simpler...

Comment: Hmm...Ubuntu 14.04 has Qt 5.2.1 in repositories and the OP wanted Qt 5.0. No need to upgrade :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install a package called `build-essential` + the Qt5 development packages you need (or `qt5-default` package). Ubuntu 14.04 has Qt 5.2.1 in the package repositories.

`build-essential` installs g++ tool chain and `qt5-default` installs the Qt5 development libraries.

Comment: Thanks @juzzlin, I had not expressed myself clearly... but your answer is exactly what I needed and the compile now works with build-essential and qt5-default

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.io/) is *not* a compiler. It is a toolkit framework library coded for C++.

You need at least a [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) compiler, like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (`g++`, at least [4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/)) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) (`clang++`)

You probably want to say that you don't need the [QtCreator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) editor and [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).